# What is a motherboard nut setter?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building

I'm building a PC, and with the case I have something called a `Nut setter`, I only have one of these but I'm not sure what it is used for. Could you explain what I could possibly need this tool for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It attaches to a screwdriver with a hex shaft or an electric drill, used to drive or tighten nuts or hex pieces.

[image: Nut setter]

Comment: That's actually a pretty good picture , if I might add.

Answer (score 3):

It is used to tighten the brass stand-offs that support the motherboard.  The stand-off is a strange looking brass screw, with a tall hex head, that is itself bored and threaded to accept the screws that hold the motherboard down.  There are usually many more places in the case for these stand-offs than there are actual holes in the motherboard, so your case can be adapted for a wide variety of motherboards by changing the locations of these stand offs.  Just be sure that as many holes in the motherboard as possible have stand-offs under them, but especially NOT in where there is no hole, that would cause a short on the circuit board.

Answer (score 1):

Most "nut setters" are adapters that allow you to do up nuts using a hex-drive handle (of the sort usually used for screwdriver bits) instead of using a spanner/wrench.

Presumably your case has some hex-head screws to hold the parts of the case together and/or to hold components such as the PSU in place.